# How to do overlapping custom items in qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Like in the title. I have few objects, and i wanted to set graphics to them and overlap each other. I'm setting 18 squares (terrains). I'm adding to this terrains graphics:

`setPixmap(QPixmap(":Graphics/Terrain"));` like so.

Then i want to add frame to it. I have 4 files of format .png, every one is 200x200px. First one is terrain.png - it's a green square, second and third are frames, about 20px wide with a transparent center (with alpha channel) and the last .png file is City.png, in left corner of City.png, there is a small graphics, rest is transparent (alpha channel). When i'm trying to set the frame by the same way as terrain.png:

`setPixmap(QPixmap(":Graphics/Frame"));`

it covers all of the terrain.png graphics, despite the fact that the center of frame1.png is transparent.

Furthermore i want to add some others object like for example City.png. How to do it? Mayby exists some diffrent way except using this setPixmap function ?

Comment: QGraphicItems overlap by default, you just need to set the positions. Maybe you need to play with the z-index to achieve what you want ? I don't understand your problem, be very specific please when you ask a question : the need, the context, what you have coded/designed so far and what is failing exactly.

Comment: I'm setting 18 squares (terrains). I'm adding to this terrains graphics
`setPixmap(QPixmap(":Graphics/Terrain"));` like this. Then i want to add frame to it. I have 4 files .png, every one is 200x200px. First one is terrain - it's a green square, second and third are frames, about 20px wide with a transparent center and the last is City, in left corner of City's .png is small graphics, rest is transparent. When i'm trying to set frame `setPixmap(QPixmap(":Graphics/Terrain"));` it covers the terrain graphics

Comment: Edit your question to clarify, do not put information in the comments please :) think of the future readers !

Comment: I'm new to stack and qt so forgive me, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setPixmap` approach seems to work quite nicely, when used like this:

```
QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene();

QGraphicsPixmapItem* itemA = new QGraphicsPixmapItem();
itemA->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/NonTransparentImage.png"));
scene->addItem(itemA);

QGraphicsPixmapItem* itemB = new QGraphicsPixmapItem();
itemB->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/TransparentImage.png"));
scene->addItem(itemB);

QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
view->show();
```

As you expect, the transparent `itemB` overlaps `itemA`.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that.
For a next time, try to **omit unnecessary details** (here: image size & content) and **focus on the problem** (here: overlapping transparent images).
Also you should post the code you're stuck with, this would make it much easier to understand and help you.
See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)